# how to get access mdb table description note ? (via c++)

Tags: c++, ms-access

in Microsoft access application when we right click on one table a context menu show up, then click properties memu item a dialog will show the description of the table. My question is how to get this description via c++ ?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database - DAO, ODBC, something else? I haven't used Access in a while - do you mean a text comment associated with the table, or the schema, or something else?

Comment: Hi,Rup. Any way connecting to the database will be accept. the note mean a text comment associated with the schema, usually be used to store alias name.

Answer (score 1):

Description can be found in the table schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668764.aspx

See also: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135852.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709712(v=vs.85).aspx